# Getting posted values in WebApi 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am trying to use Web Api. I have created a Webapi controller as follow

```
public class ValidateModelController : ApiController
{
     public void Post([FromBody]RequestLogDetail logDtl)
     {

     }
 }
```

where `RequestLogDetail` is a model define by me as follow

```
public class RequestLogDetail : RequestLog
{
    public string Product;
    //public string Make { get; set; }
    //public string Model { get; set; }
    //public string ReqDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using fiddler to create a request I am using the correct path as `http://localhost:50995/api/validatemodel` and it is hitting to my controller. But the problem is when I am using values in Request Body it's not getting passed to parameter `[FromBody]RequestLogDetail logDtl`.

How can I pass the values I have also tried html page with action and method post but not working.

Comment: Could you please post body of the request which you post using fiddler?

Comment: it is 'Product=testproduct' also tried `Body:Product=testproduct`

Comment: You need to send valid json object or xml object. For example json object: {Product:"TestProduct"}. If you send json object you also need to add additional http header to your request: Content-Type = "application/json". You need to do that in order for server to understand that you are sending json data (by default it assumes that you send xml).